# How to fix react-native error after updating expo to 50.0

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, npm-run

When I run `npm run ios` in terminal, I get the below error

> error: node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: [BABEL]: expo-router/babel is deprecated in favor of babel-preset-expo in SDK 50

I tried to install babel-preset-expo, but it was already installed

Comment: I got below solution in expo blog, but it still does not solve the problem

`Remove the expo-router/babel preset in favor of babel-preset-expo and be sure to clear the Metro cache before restarting your dev server—this means running npx expo start --clear or npx expo export --clear`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Removed the expo-router/babel from babel.config.js file and it works.

Comment: To add on to this, I also had to remove the "Plugins" property for it to work in that file.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above answers and didnt work. This is how I have done it.

The Error actually says to use babel-preset-expo instead. So

run this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-expo
```

update the babel.config.js

```
    module.exports = function(api) {
      api.cache(true);
    
      const presets = ['babel-preset-expo'];
    
      return {
        presets,
      };
};
```

then clear cache:

```
npx expo start --clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Removed the **expo-router/babel** from babel.config.js and re-run your expo app/server, clearing your cache with:

```
npx expo start --clear
```